# Linear independence of basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

$\def\braket#1#2{\langle#1|#2\rangle}\def\bra#1{\langle#1}\def\ket#1{#1\rangle}$

Consider the vector space of functions $r(t)$ that are solutions of the differential equation $\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}-6\frac{dr}{dt}+9r=0$.

Given two vectors $|\ket{x_1}=e^{3t}$ and $|\ket{x_2}=te^{3t}$, I must show that they form a basis in this space. To do this, I must show that they are independent. I am not sure if I should write $\alpha|\ket{x_1}+\beta|\ket{x_2}=\alpha e
^{3t}+\beta te^{3t}=0$ and show that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are zero. Or, say $\alpha\begin{bmatrix}e^{3t}\\0\end{bmatrix}+\beta\begin{bmatrix}0\\ te^{3t}\end{bmatrix}=0$, which would give me two equations, $\alpha|\ket{x_1}=\alpha e^{3t}=0$, and $\beta|\ket{x_2}=\beta te^{3t}=0$ (a lot easier to show $\alpha$ and $\beta$ must be zero). Or, is my notation all messed up? Or, are they the same thing?

Thank you

Comment: It looks like you should be writing the first, in which case they're not linearly independent.  Take $\alpha=-\beta t$

Comment: Damn, now I'm more confused

Comment: They are independent, but now I want to know why $\alpha = -\beta t$ is not the case.

Comment: Ah you're right I didn't realize you were thinking of them as functions. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to calculate the Wronskian.

The Wronskian of a finite family $f_1,\ldots, f_n$ of functions, which are $(n – 1)$ times differentiable on an interval $I$ is defined as the determinant
$$W(f_1,\ldots,f_n)(x)=
\begin{vmatrix}
 f_1(x) & \cdots & f_n(x)  \\
 f_1'(x) & \cdots & f_n'(x)  \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 f_1^{(n-1)}(x) & \cdots & f_n^{(n-1)}(x) 
\end{vmatrix}, \ x \in I.$$

If $W(f_1,\ldots,f_n)(x) \neq 0$ for some $x \in I$, then the set $\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$ is linearly independent.

In your case, we would have that

$$W(e^{3t},te^{3t})=
\begin{vmatrix}
 e^{3t} & te^{3t}  \\
 3e^{3t} & e^{3t} + 3te^{3t}
\end{vmatrix}=e^{6t} > 0 \ \ \ \forall \ t \in \mathbb{R}.$$
Hence the set $\{e^{3t},te^{3t}\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: I remember learning about Wronskians a long time ago, but does this always hold given that they are $n-1$ times differentiable?

Comment: Yes. Just pay attention that if $W(f_1,\ldots,f_n)(x)=0 \ \ \ \forall \ x \in I$, then you can't conclude anything about the set $\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$.

Answer (score 1):

You should work on $$\forall t, \alpha e^{3t}+\beta t e^{3t}=0 \implies \alpha = \beta = 0$$

Guide:

First, let $t=0$, and you should conclude that one of them is $0$. Next evaluate them at another value to conclude.

Comment: Right on, thank you. It makes way more sense now